# WPF Datagrid DataGridTemplateColumn tab focus issue

Tags: wpf

I am facing tab issue with WPF `DataGrid` `DataGridTemplateColumn`.I need to tab twice to get the focus on to the control with in the `DataGridTemplateColumn`.I tried below way as specified in this site for this issue. But still my problem is not resolved.

```
    <my:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgCB" Margin="8,32,0,0" SelectionMode="Single"                                        GridLinesVisibility="All" FontSize="13" SelectionUnit="Cell" 
    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
    EnableColumnVirtualization="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
    CanUserSortColumns="False" 
    CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
    CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
    CanUserResizeRows="True"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Width="964" 
    Height="416">
    <my:DataGrid.Columns>
    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tis">
    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
  </Style>
 </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
 <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
 <TextBox Name="txtC" PBOValidation:TextBoxMaskBehavior.Mask="Integer" LostFocus="txtC_LostFocus" Text="{Binding Path=TIME}" GotKeyboardFocus="txtC_GotKeyboardFocus"></TextBox>
 </DataTemplate>
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</my:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:DataGrid>
```

In code behind file I am written the event handler like below.

```
private void txtC_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
            }
            catch { }
        }

private void txtC_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(sender)).Text.Trim()))
            {
                ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(sender)).Text = 0.ToString();
            }
        }
```

But still my problem is not resolved and I am getting below error:

> 'DataGridCell' targettype does not match type of element 'DataGridCell'

Please help me to resolve my tab focus issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a behavior on `DataGrid` which focus on the clicked cell on first click itself. The below behavior does the required:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

/// <summary>
/// Defines a dependency property to allow the dataGridCell to become editable in mouse single click .
/// </summary>
public class DataGridCellSingleClickEditDependency : DependencyObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The is allow single click edit property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAllowSingleClickEditProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsAllowSingleClickEdit", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridCellSingleClickEditDependency), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsAllowSingleClickEditChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is allow single click edit.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <c>true</c> if this instance is allow single click edit; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool IsAllowSingleClickEdit
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(IsAllowSingleClickEditProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(IsAllowSingleClickEditProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether [is allow single click edit changed] [the specified sender].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void IsAllowSingleClickEditChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell dataGridCell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (dataGridCell != null)
        {
            if (e.NewValue.Equals(true))
            {
                dataGridCell.GotFocus += DataGridCellGotFocusHandler;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridCell.GotFocus -= DataGridCellGotFocusHandler;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the visual parent.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static T FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element) where T : UIElement
    {
        UIElement parent = element;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            T correctlyTyped = parent as T;
            if (correctlyTyped != null)
            {
                return correctlyTyped;
            }

            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the GotFocus event of the AssociatedObject control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void DataGridCellGotFocusHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing && !cell.IsReadOnly)
        {
            if (!cell.IsFocused)
            {
                cell.Focus();
            }

            DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);

            if (dataGrid != null)
            {
                dataGrid.BeginEdit(e);
                if (dataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
                {
                    if (!cell.IsSelected)
                    {
                        cell.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
                    if (row != null && !row.IsSelected)
                    {
                        row.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now to attached over `DataGrid`, you can define a Keyed style for `DataGridCell`

```
 <Style x:Key="DataGridCellSingleClickEditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="localBehaviors:DataGridCellSingleClickEditDependency.IsAllowSingleClickEdit" Value="True" />
        </Style>
```

Not to apply over DataGrid set the CellStyle

```
<DataGrid CellStyle ="{StaticResource DataGridCellSingleClickEditStyle}">
.......
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.I added your code in my sample application.I am getting issue with setter property.I changed the setter property like below.

Comment: Have you posted any comment in above comment?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.I added your code in my sample application.I am getting issue with setter property.I changed the setter property like below. <Style x:Key="DataGridCellSingleClickEditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="PBO:DataGridCellSingleClickEditDependency.IsAllowSingleClickEdit" Value="True" />
        </Style> I am getting Type 'PBO:DataGridCellSingleClickEditDependency' was not found.I am added your class under namespace PBO.Please help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: namespace should be defined in XAML. For ex 'xmlns:PBO="clr-namespace:<Namespace of DataGridCellSingleClickEditDependency  Class>"'

Comment: Thanks for your reply.My namespace issue is resolved.But still while running the application again the same old error "'DataGridCell' TargetType does not match type of element 'DataGridCell'." is coming.For this error only you told to add this code.Can you please tell me anything else needs to add in the code to solve this error.

Comment: You don't need LostFocus and GetKeyboardFocus events now in line `<TextBox Name="txtC" PBOValidation:TextBoxMaskBehavior.Mask="Integer" LostFocus="txtC_LostFocus" Text="{Binding Path=TIME}" GotKeyboardFocus="txtC_GotKeyboardFocus"></TextBox>
`. Behavior will do the required focus selection.

Comment: I removed both events.But still the same error coming.

Comment: Have you also removed `<my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
  </Style>
 </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>?`

Comment: Have you posted any code in your comment as I did not see any? Also, would it possible for you to update your question with changed changes in another edit.

Comment: Yes I removed that code. <Window x:Class="PrBO.wndAT" xmlns:PBO="clr-namespace:PBO_Validation;assembly=PBO_Validation">
<Window.Resources><Style x:Key="DataGridCellSingleClickEditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
<Setter Property="PBO:DataGridCellSingleClickEditDependency.IsAllowSingleClickEdit" Value="True" />
</Style></Window.Resources><Grid >

Comment: <my:DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellSingleClickEditStyle}">
 <my:DataGrid.Columns> <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Time in secs"><my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate><TextBox Name="txtC" PBOValidation:TextBoxMaskBehavior.Mask="Integer" Text="{Binding Path=TIME}" ></TextBox>
</DataTemplate></my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate></my:DataGridTemplateColumn></my:DataGrid.Columns></my:DataGrid>

Comment: Now my xaml code is like above.I am getting the error "'DataGridCell' targettype does not match type of element 'DataGridCell'".Kindly inform me what is .causing this issue.

Comment: My issue is resolved,Its due to namespace I am getting that error message.By adding namespace to DataGridCell issue is resolved.<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
  </Style>